# Analytic random function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, analyticity

Let $t\in[0,1]\mapsto X_t\in[0,1]$ an analytic random function.

I'd like to say that the deterministic function $t\mapsto \mathbb{E}[X_t]$ is still analytic.

What are the minimal conditions needed? For example is it possible if I don't know anything about the integrability of the derivatives of $X_t$?